# Some CSS, worked well in dev, does not work in build version

Tags: css, vue.js

In `vue.js`, Most of `css` I used works well but
some `css` for example,

In Home.vue

```
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
...
</script>
<style>
h1 {font-size:2.6em;font-weight:bold;color: #848381;}
</style>
```

in **dev mod**, at my notebook, `h1` css works well.
But when I run `npm run build` and upload files to `aws webserver`, the color of `h1` is other color.

--- addition ---

In Chrome Dev tool, I found some part of css is auto added.
For all h1 ~ h6 tag *color:inherit* is added.
If I turn off that css, the color change to same as dev mode.

[image]

How can I fix it?
What area should I check?

Comment: `<templete>` I assume is meant to be `<template>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Dev Tools and see where the style applied to the h1 tag is declared.

Check if the style has been overwritten.

Try as follows:

```
h1 {
   font-size:2.6em !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   color: #848381 !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. From Dev Tool, I found that for all h1 ~ h6 tag "color:inherit" is added automatically.